# Apache behavior after request abort

Tags: apache, timeout, abort

I have a problem in my **apache/php** website
this is the problem:
I'm using lots of **ajax requests** in my website
when a request **timeout** is appeared , **i cannot send any other request to web server**
in webserver i can see tcp packets comming (i means that new requests can reach server and it is not a network or browser problem) but in apacha **access_log** there is no new request of mine !!
can anyone help me about this problem?
btw i test ajax request sending with extjs and jquery and test both in ff and chrome ..
thanks

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: yes, there is no error in log , it seems that my request is not reaching to apache at all

Comment: does anyone have any idea??